# POWERSHELL - copy path was not found

Tags: powershell

Trying to make a script to copy files to multiple machines with servers.txt having multiple server names

Here's the code I've used so far

```
# This file contains the list of servers you want to copy files/folders to
$a = Get-Content "C:\0000_scripts\servers.txt" 

# This is the file/folder(s) you want to copy to the servers in the $computer 
variable
$source = "C:\0000_scripts\a\*.*"

# The destination location you want the file/folder(s) to be copied to
$destination = "C$\Program Files\Autodesk\"

#The command below pulls all the variables above and performs the file copy
foreach ($computer in $a) {Copy-Item $source -Destination 
"\\$computer\$destination" -Recurse}
```

Error I get is

```
Copy-Item : The network path was not found
At C:\0000_scripts\copy2.ps1:11 char:28
+ ... ter in $a) {Copy-Item $source -Destination "\\$computer\$destination" 
...
+                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Copy-Item], IOException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.IO.IOException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.CopyItemCommand
```

Any help would be great

Thanks

Comment: Try putting this right before the copy command to make sure it is doing what you think it is: `Write-Host ('$source = {0} - Destination = "\\{1}\{2}"' -f $source, $computer, $destination)`

Comment: You can also Test-Path the destination

Comment: Also consider changing this `$destination = "C$\Program Files\Autodesk\"` to this `$destination = 'C$\Program Files\Autodesk\'`. The double quotes combined with the $ tell the interpreter that there is a varible in the string that needs to be interpolated.

Comment: $source = C:\0000_scripts\a\*.* - Destination = "\\\C$\Program Files\Autodesk\"

Comment: so it doesn't seem to be adding in the machine names to the final command

Comment: if i replace $computers with the machine name it copys.

Comment: So you have a problem with the computer names that you are supposed to be getting from "C:\0000_scripts\servers.txt". Does that file exist and does it have server names in it?

Comment: yes and stupidly one of the machines was just doing a windows update so it was copying to all the other machines and just erroring on that machine. thanks for your help all works now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are running AD with the ps module but here is a copy files script I wrote that contains a nice little gui. It can use a little refinement but change the installs to whatever folder on c:\ like `$FolderOnC="Program Files\Autodesk"`.

1. Put this script in a folder called copyfiles on c: drive then run it
2. Select the file to be copied by clicking "Get File"
3. Click the "Dir" checkbox if you want to copy the whole directory
4. Search for computers by name from domain
5. Select the computers to copy to
6. Uncheck "Ping PC First" checkbox if you cannot ping the PC but know that it is on
7. Click "Copy File"

## Powershell: Copy File Script

```
#Folder on C drive to copy to
$FolderOnC = "installs"

Add-Type -Name Window -Namespace Console -MemberDefinition '
[DllImport("Kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 nCmdShow);
'

Function Show-Console {
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 5)
}

Function Hide-Console {
$consolePtr = [Console.Window]::GetConsoleWindow()
[Console.Window]::ShowWindow($consolePtr, 0)
}

Function Get-FileName($initialDirectory)
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.windows.forms") | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
    $OpenFileDialog.initialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    $OpenFileDialog.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
    $OpenFileDialog.filename
}

[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BlogPostIII"
    x:Name="Window" Title="Copy Files Tool" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" WindowStyle="None" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="NoResize" AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" Opacity=".95" FocusManager.FocusedElement="{Binding ElementName=tb_CName}">
    <Border x:Name="MainBorder" Margin="10" CornerRadius="15" BorderThickness="10" Padding="0" Height="557" Width="706" Background="#FF4F5060">
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DSE" Color="Black" Direction="270" BlurRadius="15" ShadowDepth="3" Opacity="0.7" />
        </Border.Effect>

        <Grid x:Name="background" Width="665" Height="557" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0.4,0.4,0,-20.6">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="455*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="102*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cb_Directory" Content="Dir" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="43" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFADBD37"/>
            <Label x:Name="lb_File" Content="File to Be Copied:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="143,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="112" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFADBD37"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_GetFile" Content="Get File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="75,6,0,0" Width="60" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
            <Label x:Name="lb_FileCopy" Content="none" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="258,3,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="447" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFADBD37"/>
            <Label x:Name="lb_CName" Content="Computer Name:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="113" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="#FFADBD37"/>
            <TextBox x:Name="tb_CName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="121,32,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_FindComputers" IsDefault="True" Content="Find Computers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="251,34,0,0" Width="90" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" RenderTransformOrigin="1.437,-0.191"/>

            <ListView x:Name="lv_ADComputers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="249" Margin="17,64,-25,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="655" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="Extended">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Width="673" Header="Computers" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Computers}"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>

            <TextBox x:Name="tb_Updates" IsReadOnly = "True" AcceptsTab="True" AcceptsReturn="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" Background = "Black" Foreground = 'White' FontWeight = 'Bold' VerticalScrollBarVisibility = "Visible" Margin="17,320,-6,57.8" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <Label x:Name="lb_Updates" Content="" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="17,15,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="673" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFADBD37" Height="85" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cb_PingCheckbox" Content="Ping PC First" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="152,54.8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFADBD37" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_CopyFile" Content="Copy File" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="293,51.8,0,0" Width="86" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Top" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <Button x:Name="btn_Cancel" IsCancel="True" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="391,51.8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="86" Grid.Row="1"/>
            <CheckBox x:Name="cb_PSCheckbox" Content="Show PS Window" Height="20" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="491,51.8,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="121" FontWeight="Bold" Background="{x:Null}" Foreground="#FFADBD37" Grid.Row="1"/>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>

"@
#<ListBox x:Name="tb_ADUsers" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="319" Margin="241,34,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="308" Grid.RowSpan="2" AllowDrop="True" SelectionMode="Extended"/>

#Hide the Powershell Windows in background
    Hide-Console

Import-Module ActiveDirectory

#Global Variables
$LocalPath = $null
$RemotePath = $null
$Script:FileToCopy = $null
#$inputfile = Get-FileName "C:\powershell"
#End Global Declares

[string]$scriptPath = split-path $SCRIPT:MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -parent

# Initialize the Windows Presentation Framework
    Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

# Create an object for the XML content
    $xamlReader = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml

# Load the content so we can start to work with it
    $mainform = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($xamlReader)
# To see what options are avaliable
#   $mainform | Get-member Add* -MemberType Method -force > c:\powershell\get-member-main-form.txt

# Store Form Objects
    $xaml.SelectNodes("//*") | %{Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $mainform.FindName($_.Name)}
    
# Make Window Draggable
    $mainform.Add_MouseDown({$this.DragMove()})

    
##################MAPS###################   

#Map: Output Textbox
    $tb_Updates = $mainform.FindName('tb_Updates')
#Action: Cancel Button
    $btn_Cancel.Add_Click({$mainform.Close()})
#Map: Ping/NoPing Checkbox
    $cb_PingCheckbox.IsChecked = $true
#Map: Show/Hide Powershell Windows Checkbox
    $cb_PSCheckbox.Add_Checked({Show-Console})
    $cb_PSCheckbox.Add_UnChecked({Hide-Console})

##################ACTIONS###################

#Action: Get Filename - Clicked##
    $btn_GetFile.Add_Click({
    $FileToCopy = Get-FileName("C:\copyfiles")
    If ($cb_Directory.IsChecked -eq $true){
    $FileToCopy = Split-Path $FileToCopy
    $lb_FileCopy.Content = $FileToCopy
    $tb_Updates.Text = "Directory: $FileToCopy `r"
    }
    Else{
    $lb_FileCopy.Content = $FileToCopy
    $tb_Updates.Text = "File: $FileToCopy `r"
    }
    })
#Action: Find Computers - Clicked##
    $btn_FindComputers.Add_Click({
    $CName = $tb_CName.Text
    $tb_Updates.AppendText(("{0}`r" -f "Finding Computers $CName"))
    #Clear the Users ListBox
        $lv_ADComputers.Items.Clear()
    if(!($CName -eq "")){Get-ADComputer -Filter "Name -like '$CName*'" | sort-object Name | ForEach {[void] $lv_ADComputers.Items.Add([PSCustomObject]@{Computers = $_.Name})}}
    })
#Action: Copy Files - Clicked##
    $btn_CopyFile.Add_Click({
    #Map: Computers Listbox to Variables
        $ADComputers = $lv_ADComputers.SelectedItems.Computers

    if(!($ADComputers -eq $null)){
        $tb_Updates.Clear
        
        #Start of Copying File
        ForEach ($Computer in $ADComputers){
            $script:DestPC = $Computer
            If ($cb_PingCheckbox.IsChecked -eq $true){
                If (-not (Test-Connection -quiet -count 1 -computer $Computer)) {
                $tb_Updates.AppendText(("{0}`r" -f "$Computer is Offline"))
                }
                Else{
                    $tb_Updates.AppendText(("{0}`r" -f "Copying File to $Computer"))
                    $FileToCopy = $lb_FileCopy.Content
                    Copy-Item "$FileToCopy" "\\$Computer\c$\$FolderOnC" -recurse -force
                    $tb_Updates.AppendText(("{0}`r" -f "File copied to $Computer"))
                    $tb_Updates.ScrollToEnd();

                }
            }
            Else{
                $FileToCopy = $lb_FileCopy.Content
                $tb_Updates.AppendText(("{0}`r" -f "Copying File to $Computer"))
                Copy-Item "$FileToCopy" "\\$DestPC\c$\$FolderOnC" -recurse -force
            }
        }
    }
    Else{$tb_Updates.Text = "No Computers Selected"}
    })#End of CopyFile Button Click

# Show the form
    $mainform.ShowDialog() | Out-Null
```